# How can I get Excel to copy every nth cell from one sheet onto another?

Tags: excel

My data starts in C9 and I want to reference every 18th row. For example (the referenced sheet is named Summer):

=+Summer!C9

=+Summer!C27

=+Summer!C45

How can I get excel to recognize this pattern so I don't have to type it over and over?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not pretty, but you can do something like this:

```
=indirect("Summer!C" & (Row()*18-9))
```

Basically use the current row as a multiplier, and construct the formula.

Edit:
Indirect is a function that allows you to use a cell reference you have constructed from a string. So we're actually trying to contruct:

```
=indirect("Summer!C9")
```

which evaluates the same as your original

```
=Summer!C9
```

So all we need to do is compute the number 9 from whatever we have handy. To find the right math to calculate the number you want, lets test this simpler version:

```
=(Row()-n+1)*18)-9)
```

This should give you a number. Replace *n* with the row number where you *first* formula appears. So if your first formula was actually on row 25, you'd instead use:

```
=(Row()-25+1)*18)-9)
```

Once you are sure the *number* is correct, then just tack on the

```
=indirect("Summer!C" &
```

portion and you should be good to go. Note I've also assumed that each formula is in the row below the previous one. If that's not the case, then you'd have to make other adjustments. But its all just math.

Comment: This did not work for me... What cell does it have to be in on the new sheet? I am not using A1. Can you please break the formula down too (what does everything mean)? Thanks!

Comment: awesome! it worked! thanks for checking back! one more add on if you dont mind... how can i now copy this across columns? it would need to reference the same column as the other sheet.

Comment: So you want the column to vary, too? that's a bit tougher, because it is normally a letter, not a number. BUT, the INDIRECT function has the ability to work with R1C1-style notation, if you include a second parameter of FALSE. I don't have time to debug it all, but you'd want to ultimately generate something like: =indirect("Summer!R" & rownum & "C" & colnum, FALSE) where "rownum" and "colnum" are formulas that give you the correct row and column number.

Comment: Thanks Brad! You really have helped!

Answer (score 1):

if you just need numbers mixed in with words above and below you could do a filter and then a select visible cells only and paste into a new sheet